# Can't load image into buffered image 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedimage

```
File newFile = null;
    BufferedImage oldImage = null;
    BufferedImage newImage = null;
    String fileName = new String((args[0]));

    String newFileName = new String(fileName.replaceFirst(".png", "-tiled.png"));

    try{
        oldImage = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));
        System.out.println("Reading Complete");
                }
    catch(IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Error: "+ e);
    }

    int width = oldImage.getWidth();
    int height = oldImage.getHeight();
    newImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    int imagePixels [][] = new int [height][width];
        for (int i = 0; i < height -1; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width - 1; ++j) {
            imagePixels[i][j] = oldImage.getRGB(i,j); //error here

            }
    }
```

It compiles fine, however when I run the program, it will run perfectly for a 10x10 image, however when I try and use a 800x600 image it will not work, and error occurs on the commented line saying that

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Coordinate out of bounds!
    at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.getDataElements(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB(Unknown Source)
    at imagery.ImageTiler.main(ImageTiler.java:35)
```

Can anyone spot this irritating error?

A little side info: The program gets a file name from command line and then loads the RGB pixels into a 2D Array.

Any help is appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Try swapping ++i and ++j with i++ and j++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the coordinates the wrong way around in the `getRGB` call.  The image height is in the Y direction, but you are using height for the bounds of `i` ... the X coordinate.

[This page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/overview/coordinate.html) explains the Java image coordinate system.

Comment: YOU BEAUTY!
That's the issue right there, swapped i and j around and it works perfectly. No wonder it worked for an image with the same width and height! Duh!

Thanks a lot dude!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < width -1; ++i) {
for (int j = 0; j < height - 1; ++j) {
    imagePixels[i][j] = oldImage.getRGB(i,j); //error here

}
```

this will draw the array the right way i think..